# Load and reload content from other page

Tags: php, jquery

I would like to place content from another php page in my div and reload this every ten seconds. Currently, I use the following code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
$("#screen").load('https://www.url.com/test.php')
}, 10000);
});
</script>

<div id="screen"></div>
```

That works great, but I need something that loads the content immediately and then reloads every 10 seconds. Does anyone have any idea? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just make the load-call a separate function, call it before the first interval and in each interval and probably use curl or file_get_contents to load the content at pageload using PHP

Comment: That sounds great, but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @vloryan i have posted an answer below, please tell me if you need any more help.

Comment: You need a 10s between data reload or between data load start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

function update_screen(){
   $("#screen").load('https://www.url.com/test.php');
}

update_screen();
setInterval("update_screen", 10000);

});
</script>

<div id="screen"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately nothing happens at all when I use these lines? The page isn't even loaded. Any idea?

Comment: @vloryan try now, i fixed a typo and tested it locally

Comment: Loading the first instance took a little long, so I have used `<?php include 'https://www.url.com/test.php';?>` inside the div first and the `setInterval(function(){...`. Works great and the content shows up much faster.

Comment: @vloryan use `file_get_contents` instead, `include` could execute any provided php code http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#example-162.